# What type of glue to stick paper on paper without curling?

Tags: paper, adhesives, cardboard

I want to make super thick invitation cards. When I use white glue, it looks great for a day but then it starts curling.

Any idea what I can use ?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about "super thick" -- is it two thick pieces of paper being stuck together, paper onto cardstock, etc.? What's the [paper weight](https://www.paperpapers.com/paper-weights.html)? The better we understand your project, the better answers you'll get :)

Comment: Two sheets of 350gsm

Comment: This is super related: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/77/why-have-my-paper-crafts-hung-on-the-wall-deformed-and-what-can-be-done-to-preve/346#346

Answer (score 6):

Glue stick doesn’t curl paper. You have to be careful what brand you chose, though (some just don’t stick well). Of the ones I know *UHU stic* would be a good choice – it’s quite strong.

Comment: This! Pretty much what glue sticks were invented for.

Answer (score 5):

I just did this - I wanted to make thick business cards myself, but my printer won't print on any paper thicker than regular copy paper. So I printed my card template out on regular paper and then used **iron-on sewing interfacing** (Wonder Under) to glue it to thick watercolor paper. No bubbles, looks great - made some cards with one layer of 110 pound paper and one with 2 layers of 110 pound paper and one layer of colored cardstock in the middle - here's a pic!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[YES paste](http://www.joann.com/yes-paste-all-purpose-stick-flat-glue/1099100.html) is a glue often used in book-making, because it is more reliable and provides a higher-quality result. You can also dilute the glue to match the heaviness of the paper, which can greatly reduce curling as well.

Edit: Another solution is to leave your cards under a flat weight (like a big book) for the first 30 minutes of dry time. This will help with adhesion and limit how much the paper can pull away. Watch out for exposed glue though, which can stick to the book and tear up your work.

Comment: I would be careful about diluting any glue for paper with water. In my experience that is the reason for curling and bubbling.

Comment: @Nothingismagick Care is of course recommended, but the product is designed to be used this way. Its normal thickness is at least twice the viscosity of acrylic paint, which can cause its own problems with certain kinds of paper.

Comment: one of the reviews on that product page says: will not buckle due to low moisture content. Sure, you can thin it with water because it is water-based, but paper “cockles” unless the whole sheet is wet when you add watery glue to one side. This is one of the reasons that you soak a sheet of paper before running it through a press where you’ll be using water-based inks. It is also why you coat both sides of wallpaper with your wallpaper glue.

Answer (score 2):

Try either an acrylic medium or PVA glue (like the kind for woodworking). After applying it to one or both sides and spreading it out VERY evenly, place the glued pieces between two layers of waxed paper and then press with a heavy weight or clamp between two boards for 24 hours.

Don’t dilute it with water, because that’s a great way to introduce wrinkles.

Answer (score 2):

Expensive but - how about spraymount? Might be worth using for such an expensive/important multi item project - where weighting every sheet as it dries is going to take you forevvver. I would try it on a few first, and try stacking 5 or ten cards with a larger flat sheet of card and a weight on top like a heavy flat book, as they dry.

Answer (score 1):

Try ensuring that you glue papers of the same thickness as I believe the different gsms (weight of paper) might cause curling as they dry

Comment: Hello Chris and welcome to A&C!  
Is there any way of elaborating more on your answer?    
Having a visual or example of your  answer might be helpful for others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Super glue. I have been using super glue to attach pieces of cereal box card together to make pieces of smaller structures like boxes. It sets solid in ~10 seconds. Some practice is needed to make sure that the glue isn't too close to the edges as there will be some spreading. Do around the edges and a couple of fixing spots in the middle. With the box structures I was making the edges could be sanded.